# Is there any better option for checkin if a substring is numeric?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a long string. In the string, there are numbers and other kinds of symbols (text). I need to store the words and numbers separately. Firstly, I have the string split by spaces.

```
String fullString = "Some 3 random 5.6 text 12 with -4.5 numbers -1 in 0 beetween";
String [] words = fullString.split(" ");
```

I've made a method to check if the method `Double.parseDouble()` trows and exception on each substring stored in `words` variable.

```
private static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
       return false;
    }
    try {
       double parseDouble = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In my code, when I get a `true` I will have to run twice the method `Double.parseDouble(str)`.

```
for(String word: words){
    if(isNumeric(word)){
        numbers.push = Double.parseDouble(word);
    }
}
```

I think I am looking for any of these two options:

1. An easier method to check if the substring stored in `words` is a number.
2. Another way to parse the double just once.

Comment: you could remove the words with regex then split and know the rest are numbers

Comment: also there is a function call isNaN that will (Not a Number) which will test if a string is any form of number including exponent expressions and stuff. It will return false if the string is considered a valid number.

Comment: Maybe try using regex. Your ```isNumeric()``` could in fact become a simple ```word.matches("[\d]+")```.

Comment: You can try the  NumberUtils from Apache Commons library.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-string-number

Comment: One catch: you have some other characters apart from digits and alphanumeric. What do you want to do with those?

Comment: @user16320675 Oops that is javascrip.. I am sure there is an equivalent in appache commons StringUtils.isNumeric(), I do not like using a hand made one because for lots of things like that because there are always things we forget.. aka infinities, numbers like 3.2e10, silly things like negative numbers. etc.. so I prefer to use a lib, for things I know I am not the only one that had that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case if using `Double.parseDouble()` is a good enough indicator if the String is numeric or not, and you just want to avoid running the same method twice, once for validation and once for actual parsing than you can use MgntUtils Open source library that has the following method in class TextUtils:

```
public static double parseStringToDouble(java.lang.CharSequence num,
                                         double defaultValue)
```

You can use it in such a way:

```
Double num = TextUtils.parseStringToDouble(parsedStr, Double.MIN_VALUE);
if(Double.MIN_VALUE.equals(num)) {
  treatStringAsNotNumeric(parsedStr);
} else {
  treatStringAsNumeric(num /* or may be parsedStr*/);
}
```

The library is available as a [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (Including source code and Javadoc). Javadoc online also available [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/)

**Disclaimer:** The library is written by me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have commons-lang3 you can do;

Extended -> matches also numbers like 0xFF 0e0 0L

```
Arrays.stream(words).filter(NumberUtils::isCreatable).toArray()
```

Simple version -> matches like 0 -0 0.0 .0

```
Arrays.stream(words).filter(Pattern.compile("^-?(\\d+|(\\.\\d+)|(\\d+\\.\\d+))$").asPredicate()).toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing about strings is that numerical values can be supplied within the string in so many different formats some of which will never pass by a numerical parser like `Integer.parseInt()` or `Double.parseDouble()`. The below **isNumeric()** method can handle quite a few of the most common ones, at least those used in North America. Some modification to the [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) used in the **isNumeric()** method code below within the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method would need to be done to the handle other specific numerical notation formats used in other parts of the world.

**The isNumeric() method:**

```
/**
 * Returns true if the string is a numerical type value.
 * 
 * The Regular Expression (regex) used here covers just about any provided 
 * numerical values like:<pre>
 * 
 *    "05", "0",   "18", "-12", "-33.0", "0.33", "-22.8", ".675E8", 
 *    "-.322", "44.343e6", "+453", "+94.234, 1,234.87, 32,043,001"
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @param numericalString (String)
 * 
 * @return (boolean)
 */
public static boolean isNumeric(String numericalString) {
    /* Utilization of the String#matches() method.
       The String#replace() method is used to remove commas in numbers.
       These commas should also be removed before parsing to a specific 
       numerical data type (wherever that might be in your code).                         */
    return numericalString.replace(",", "").matches("[-+]?(\\d+)?(\\.(\\d+)?((?i)E\\d+)?)?");
}
```

**How the isNumeric() method might be used:**

```
// The string to work against.
String fullString = "Some 3 random 5.6 text 12 with -4.5 numbers -1 "
                  + "in 0 between. These are added 05 0 18 -12 -33.0 0.33 "
                  + "-22.8 .675E8 -.322 44.343e6 +453 +94.234 1,234.87 "
                  + "32,043,001 as well!";
    
/* Split the contents of fullString based on one or more 
   whitespaces as delimiter. This takes care of any strings
   that may have double-spacing anywhere within it.      */
String [] words = fullString.split("\\s+");
    
/* Because we may never know how large any given string may 
   be, We use the List Interface or ArrayList object to 
   create a collection of both words and double numerical 
   values. Either of these object can grow dynamically (as
   can may other objects). Arrays can not grow dynamically.
   You can convert these Lists to Arrays later if you really 
   like.                                      */
List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
    
/* Iterate through the 'words' array and add alpha character
   words to the 'wordsList' list and numerical values (if any)
   to the 'numbersList' list. In this example all string number
   values will be converted to Double data type (also handles 
   Exponents).         */
for (String wordStrg : words) {
    if (isNumeric(wordStrg)) {
        // The String#replace() method id used to remove commas in numbers.
        numbersList.add(Double.parseDouble(wordStrg.replace(",", "")));
    }
    else {
        wordsList.add(wordStrg);
    }
}
    
// Show what is in the Lists:
System.out.println("The Words List:");
System.out.println(wordsList);
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The Numbers List (as Double):");
System.out.println(numbersList);
    
// ==============================================================
// If for some reason you want to convert the Lists 
// to arrays then you can do it this way:
String[] onlyWords = wordsList.toArray(new String[wordsList.size()]);
Double[] onlyNumbers = numbersList.toArray(new Double[numbersList.size()]);
    
// Display The Arrays:
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The Words Array:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(onlyWords));
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The Numbers Array (as Double):");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(onlyNumbers));
```